# Fixing 1px bug in safari

Tags: html, css

My site has a 1px white space on the right which you only can see in safari and on scroll events (in safari), I have already tried google but can't find a working answer. This is the site I'm working on http://development.sakesalverda.nl/Hotel/home/ but what is the problem and why is that 1px gab only there on safari?

Comment: Does this help? `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
` Try `@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 

html {
    margin-left: 1px;
}

}` also.

Comment: Sorry, none of theme works :(

Comment: [And this](http://philfreo.com/blog/fixing-safaris-1px-background-image-centering-problem/)?